# How to fix this error?

Tags: system

My Ubuntu's operation doesn't complete and this appears to me. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried booting into recovery console? limiting boot to runlevel 1?   Can you switch to a text terminal and login?   I'd try and boot to terminal or by switching to terminal, login to tty and explore what was done last session as to what changed as it will provide clues are to fix; this detail should be provided to us if for your best chance of useful advice. I might also boot a 'live' system and `fsck` your disk if twas me (use sysrq keys to reboot, **not** power-off)

Comment: Were you running from a LiveDVD or LiveUSB to try to install Ubuntu? If so, which version? Did you checksum-verify https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 the downloaded ISO file before making the live media? Which version number is in use? Please click [edit] and add that very useful information to the question; please don't use Add Comment, but use [edit] instead.